# C++: how does C++ know to destruct smart pointers inside containers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

In The C++ Programming Language, there is the following example (section
3.2.4).

```
unique_ptr<Shape> read_shape(istream& is);

void user()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Shape>> v;
    while (cin)
        v.push_back(read_shape(cin));
    draw_all(v);
    // call draw() for each element
    rotate_all(v,45);
    // call rotate(45) for each element
} // all Shapes implicitly destroyed
```

Stroustrup is trying to make the point that by using unique_ptrs, one
doesn't have to manually loop through the vector and delete all
Shapes. I'm having trouble understanding why this is true.

The way I understand smart pointers is that if a smart pointer sptr is
allocated on the stack, with something like

```
std::unique_ptr<Shape> sptr(new Shape());
```

you don't need to call delete on it at the end of the function. However,
from what I can tell in the above example those smart pointers are not
on the stack, they're put inside the data array of v, which is on the
heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is on the stack or the heap doesn't really matter.  What matters is that it will automatically call `delete` on the target pointer when its destructor runs.

When the `vector` goes out of scope, the vector's [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/%7Evector) runs.  That destroys all contained elements (calling their destructors in the process) and then deallocates its heap buffer.

Comment: I see. I didn't know the vector destructor did this. What happens if a vector containing an object goes out of scope but you don't want to destruct that object?

Comment: @extremeaxe5 then you move that object out of the container

Answer (score 1):

This is what destructors are for. You don't see the "manual loop" that destroys the unique pointers because that loop is within the destructor of the vector. All containers destroy their elements.

Answer (score 1):

When the destructor for `std::vector` runs it calls the destructor for each object it contains. The destructor for `std::unique_ptr` calls `delete`/`delete[]` on the pointer it wraps, so all of the memory that was allocated will be cleaned up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you create something on the heap, you have to delete it yourself. Unlike automatic variables (those on the stack, even though the standard doesn't actually mandate the existence of a stack), the lifetime (scope) of those objects can continue across function return boundaries.

However, the *vector* here is not on the heap - it's actually an automatic variable that will undoubtedly store *some* of its information on the heap (the array holding the vector elements, most likely), but the variable itself is not.

That means, when it goes out of scope on exit from `user()`, the destructor is called for it. That destructor is smart enough to free the heap-specific stuff for the vector itself, *and* call the destructor for each element in the vector.

And, of course, destructing each of those elements may cause further destructors to be called. If one of those elements being destructed is a smart pointer, *it* will know that it needs to release its hold on the underlying pointer, by either freeing it or decrementing a count to say it has no further interest in it.

Answer (score 1):

When a `std::unique_ptr` itself is destructed or reset, it calls `delete` or `delete[]` (or a custom `deleter` that you specify) on the object/array that it is currently holding a pointer to.

If the `std::unique_ptr` is created in *automatic* memory, such as the stack, it is destructed when it goes out of scope.

If the `std::unique_ptr` is created in *dynamic* memory, such as the heap, it is destructed when `delete` is called on it.

A container owns the elements that it stores.  It knows whether its elements are of a type that defines a destructor or not, and if so then it will call that destructor on each element when needed, such as when removing individual elements from the container, or when the container itself is destructed or cleared.

So, if you have a container of `std::unique_ptr` elements, they will be destructed for you when appropriate, which in turn will destruct the things that they are pointing at.